# Laravel Passport custom hasher to create token

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have used a SHA1 hash for a password like this:
https://arjunphp.com/laravel-5-sha1-encryption-instead-of-bcrypt/

Now I am using passport API to create a token, but it is not allowing me to create a token as the hasher is changed now.

> Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Argument 1 passed to Laravel\Passport\Bridge\UserRepository::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Hashing\HashManager, instance of App\Libraries\ShaHash\SHAHasher given in file C:\xampp1\htdocs\coursekartv2\vendor\laravel\passport\src\Bridge\UserRepository.php on line 26

How can I override `UserRepository` to use `SHAHasher` instead of `HashManager`? Or any other help to overcome this issue.

Comment: It clearly says that `UserRepository::__construct() must be an instance of Illuminate\Hashing\HashManager` so pass variable instance of UserRepositroy.

Comment: @Iftikharuddin I know why it is giving error, my question is how to override userrepositry and force it to use my custom hasher i.e SHAHasher

Comment: In simple words, my question is if you use Laravel-Custom-Hashing then how to use same for passport. As it is verifying credential while creating token using hashManager which i already changed using custom. I can't pass hashManager instance.

Comment: if you want to override i think you need to replace the base code with a variable. e.g if in base code there is `Class instance` as parameter so replace it with just a `variable`. Try this and let me know.

Comment: I don't want to change base code, as it is not best practice. But yes i have tried by changing base code, and it work obviously. Thanks for putting your time, let me know if i can achive without changing base code.

Comment: @Iftikharuddin Thanks for putting your time, but my colleague solve the issue. I was using my custom hasher insted of hashManager, he told me extend HashManager of passport instead of complete new hasher (SHAHasher). So now even i am sending SHAHasher (custom) it is accepting as my SHAHasher extends hashManager.

Comment: good to know, keep rocking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the solution:

I was using my custom hasher (SHAHasher) instead of Passport hashManager, now extend HashManager of passport instead of complete new hasher (SHAHasher). So now even i am sending SHAHasher (custom) it is accepting as my SHAHasher extends hashManager.

Extend hashManager inside custom hasher library.

Answer (score 3):

we came across the same problem as the one described here, I am working on a Laravel API that needs to handle Passport and also has it own custom Hasher (SHA1). like the one in [here](https://arjunphp.com/laravel-5-sha1-encryption-instead-of-bcrypt/)

Our fix for this was not only make our class ShaHasher extends HashManager
like so:

```
class ShaHasher extends HashManager implements Hasher { ..... }
```

you also need to make sure that your provider for this Hasher get and instance of the $app container in the constructor  like so:

```
<?php


namespace App\Providers;


use Illuminate\Hashing\HashServiceProvider;
use Psytech\ShaHasher;

class ShaHashServiceProvider extends HashServiceProvider {

    public function register()
    {
       $this->app->singleton('hash', function () {
           return new ShaHasher($this->app);
       });
    }

}
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: as a final note our Laravel version is currently 5.8.19

Comment: Thanks a lot of.It help me

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a custom hasher and extend the existing HashManager with your custom hashing using the extend method on the HashManager

In the AuthServiceProvider:

```
$this->app->get('hash')->extend('custom_hasher', function(){
    return new CustomHasher();
});
```

In the hash.php config file you can then change the hash driver:

```
'driver' => 'custom_hasher',
```